# Find the mistake - 4th order homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following $4$th order ODE:

$\varphi''''+\varphi=0$

---

I've tried the standard approach and computed the zeros of $x^4+x$, which consist of $0,\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}),-1,\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})-i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$.
This gives us the general solution $\varphi(x)=c_1e^{0t}+c_2e^{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})t}\cdot \cos(\sin(\pi/3))+c_3e^{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})t}\cdot\sin(\sin(\pi/3))+c_4e^{-t}$, however, when I plot $\varphi$ and $\varphi''''$, I can see that this does in fact not solve the ODE. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You need the zeros of $x^4+1$.

Comment: Moreover, you need the $t$ in $\cos(\sin(\pi/3)t)$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the DE: $$y''''+y=0$$
The polynomial characteristic should be:
$$r^4+1=0$$
And not:
$$r^4+r=0$$